# how to pass current date in python when using os. system for copying files to a gcs location in python 2.7.5

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python script which moves file from local dir to a gs:// using os.system. I need to pass today's date to the filename in the gcs bucket.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import requests
import csv
import json
import os
from datetime import date


#current_date = date.today()

def uploadfile2GCSraw():
    current_date = date.today()
    os. system('gsutil cp /u/y/XXXX/abcd.json  gs://XXXX/XX/XX/CRE_DT=current_date')
```

Im very new to python, when i run the above, the file is created as cre_dt=current_date, as is. its not taking the date from date.today(). Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you have current_date on that final line, it's going to literally be the string current_date.

Try using an f-string, like this:

```
os.system(f"gsutil cp /u/y/XXXX/abcd.json  gs://XXXX/XX/XX/CRE_DT={current_date}")
```

For older python 2, use this syntax:

```
os.system("gsutil cp /u/y/XXXX/abcd.json gs://XXXX/XX/XX/CRE_DT=%s"%(date.today()))
```

(And then upgrade to Python 3.)

Should do what you want.

Comment: Oh, I think that's because as noted by another user, there was a space between your os and .system, and I got that in my cut and paste. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Even with space, the function worked. the file is created, but no date.

Comment: Are you sure that date.today() is working on your system? To debug, maybe replace os.system with print, and instead of current_time just do {date.today()} directly in the f-string . . . that code works fine for me. Like this: print(f"gsutil cp /u/y/XXXX/abcd.json  gs://XXXX/XX/XX/CRE_DT={date.today()}")

Comment: Looks like date.today() is not working. Im using python 2.7. Is there any alternative. I tried your print and it throwed the same error.

Comment: I would start a new question or maybe update this one around why that one liner doesn't work, include the whole output with just from datetime import date and that one liner along with your system details. That's the weird part here, that could should basically always work.

Comment: Actually wait, how old is your version of 2.7? It might not support f-strings.

Comment: Python 2.7.5 it is.

Comment: I just updated the answer with Python 2 compatible syntax, that should get you going. Python 2 has been EOL for a while now -- if you absolutely can't upgrade, I'd lead with "I'm on Python 2.7.5" when asking questions.

Comment: Thanks Matt.Im sorry if you didnt notice, but i tagged the pythin 2.7, but yeah, will start the question with the version from next time.

Comment: Ah, you sure did. But yeah, that version with the old style % string interpolation should do what you want.

Comment: using the second option worked for me, Thank you so much. Appreciate it!!